# Accessing localserver through Android

Tags: php, android, android-studio, localserver

I have this code:

```
     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        InetAddress ip;
        mWebview  = new WebView(this);
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        final Activity activity = this;
        String ipv4add;
        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        ipv4add = ip.getHostAddress().toString();
        System.out.println(ipv4add);
        mWebview .loadUrl(ipv4add+"/Lab4/Task1/index.php");
            mWebview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        setContentView(mWebview );
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So what it does exactly is first: it should get the server ip that the phone is supposed to be connected to, then after that it will be inserted into the URL so that the phone can connect to the localserver and access my php files. However, when I launch this into my android phone it just crashes. Why does it do so? Hoping you guys can help me solve this.

Comment: so what did you get on `System.out.println(ipv4add)`? what is the extected value?

Comment: @user1506104 it displays the IP of the server. As for mine, it displays 192.168.1.105

Comment: this is the address of your phone. are you trying to get the ip of your server in your local network?

Comment: Well I tried putting that address into my phone's browser and I can access my php files so I presumed that is my server address

Comment: do you have the `android.permission.INTERNET` in your manifest?

Comment: yes I have that included

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to dynamically request for your server's IP. Or do you? What you can do is get the static IP address of your server (by checking your server's IP configuration) and change to this

`mWebview .loadUrl("http://your.ip.address.here/Lab4/Task1/index.php");`

and remove your

```
ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
ipv4add = ip.getHostAddress().toString();
```

Once you are ready to deploy to live, the `192.168.1.x` will have to be replaced with your live domain such as

`mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.yourdomain.com/Lab4/Task1/index.php");`

Also, don't forget this in your manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Well it needs to be dynamic since I'm just testing it at home.